# SED error - invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS extracting XML text

Tags: linux, sed

I have an XML file with multiple lines like below.

```xml
<sandbox>false</sandbox>
<serverUrl>https://salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0/</serverUrl>
<sessionId>00D4100000087K9!AQMAQJElzjgvA01eaCo</sessionId>
<userId>00541000000JOzJAAW</userId>
<userInfo>
```

I am trying to use sed on Linux to get a value between the two sessionId tags.

```
sed -n '/<sessionId>.*$/{s/<sessionId>.*<\/sessionId>/\1/;p}' LoginResponse.xml
```

But it is throwing the below error.
Any suggestions please...

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 50: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: I used round brackets but still getting the same error.                                  sed -n '/<sessionId>.*$/{s/<sessionId>(.*)<\/sessionId>/\1/;p}' LoginResponse.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Right Thing

Don't use `sed` for this at all; XML is not a regular language, so [regular expressions are categorically not powerful enough to parse it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Your current code can't distinguish a comment that talks about sessionId tags from a real sessionId tag; can't recognize element encodings; can't deal with unexpected attributes being present on your tag; etc.

Instead, use:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//sessionId' -v . -n < LoginResponse.xml
```

...or, if you don't have XMLStarlet, you can use XSLTProc (which is almost universally available out-of-the-box on modern UNIXy systems). If you save the following as `extract-session-id.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- this was generated with:
  -- xmlstarlet sel -C -t -m '//sessionId' -v . -n
  -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//sessionId">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...then you can run `xsltproc extract-session-id.xslt LoginResponse.xml` to get your output.

---

#### The `sed` Thing

That said, with respect to your `sed` bug: You need to pass `-r` to enable ERE syntax:

```
# requires GNU sed for -r
sed -r -n -e '/<sessionId>.*$/{s/<sessionId>(.*)<\/sessionId>/\1/;p}'
```

Alternately, with the MacOS BSD sed, some other tweaks are needed:

```
# -E, not -r, on MacOS BSD sed; semicolon between "p", "}" needed.
sed -E -n '/<sessionId>.*$/ { s/<sessionId>(.*)<\/sessionId>/\1/; p; }'
```

This will behave badly if your session IDs ever include characters that are behind elements -- `&`s will look like `&amp;` and so forth; using a proper XML parser is thus the safer option. (Likewise, if the content ever changed so `<sessionid type="foo">...</sessionid>`, or in the event of any manner of other changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Charles Duffy for your suggestion. Using -r option with Sed fixed the issue. It is also good to know about the xmlstarlet option. Both worked great.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you for using the proper XML parser like xmlstarlet instead of sed. Thanks again for your detailed answer, I truly appreciate it.