# Use sed for Mixed Case Tags

Tags: sed, windows-10, gnu-sed

Trying to reformat tags in an xlm file with gnu sed v4.7 on win10 (shoot me). `sed` is in the path and run from the Command Prompt. Need to escape some windows command-line characters with `^`.

**sourcefile**

```
BEGIN
...
   <trn:description>V7906 03/11 ALFREDOCAMEL HATSWOOD 74564500125</trn:description>
...
END
```

(There are three spaces at the start of the line.)

**Expected output:**

```
BEGIN
...
   <trn:description>V7906 03/11 Alfredocamel Hatswood 74564500125</trn:description>
...
END
```

I want Title Case but this does in-place to lower case:

`sed -i 's/^<trn:description^>\(.*\)^<\/trn:description^>$/^<trn:description^>\L\1^<\/trn:description^>/g' sourcefile`

[This command changes to Title Case](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/command-line-text-processing/content/gnu_sed.html#changing-case):

`sed 's/.*/\L^&/; s/\w*/\u^&/g' sourcefile`

Can this be brought together as a one-liner to edit the original sourcefile in-place?

---

I want to use sed because it is available on the system and the code is consistently structured. I'm aware I [should use a tool like xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667659/4539999) as explained:

> sed ... code can't distinguish a comment that talks about sessionId tags from a real sessionId tag; can't recognize element encodings; can't deal with unexpected attributes being present on your tag; etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Whirlpool Forum members for the [answer and discussion](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/thread/3rp45163).

It was too hard to achieve pattern matching "within the tags" in sed and the file was well formed so the required lines were changed:

`sed -i.bak '/^<trn:description^>/s/\w\+/\L\u^&/g; s/^&.*;\^|Trn:Description/\L^&/g' filename`

**Explanation**

- in-place edit saving original file with `.bak` extension
- select lines containing `<trn:description>`
- for one or more words
- replace first character with uppercase and rest with lowercase
- select strings starting with `&` and ending with `;` or `Trn:Description`
- restore codes by replacing characters with lowercase
- source/target `filename`

Note: `^` is windows escape character and is not required in other implementations